# Extract an instance of the associated type of an enum

Tags: swift, enums

I have the following

```
case noSpaces
case noCoverImage
case noSpacePhotos(for: Space)
case noName(for: Issue)
case noIssuePhotos(for: Issue)
case noIssueComment(for: Issue)
case noSpaceComment(for: Space)
```

When I catch the error, I just want to grab the instance of the associated type.

```
} catch let error as MissingElementError {
    //just get instance of associated type, if any
}
```

Is there a way I can do this without writing out a switch statement and all possible cases?

Comment: Yes, with a Mirror, but you've still got two types there. Doesn't seem worth bothering with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Expanding on a comment made by Jessy.

If I made each type conform to a protocol and then used Mirror...

```
protocol Reflectable {
    var title: String { get }
}

struct Issue: Reflectable {}
struct Space: Reflectable {}

} catch let error as MissingElementError {
    if let some = Mirror(reflecting: error).children.first?.1 as? Reflectable {

    }
}
```

Comment: Casting to a protocol that has no properties and/or methods seems pointless

Comment: The content of the protocol is beyond the scope of this post, but if you really need me to put a property in there..l. There ya go, title.